# Como alterar o foco das abas de um TabHost?

Tags: android

Tenho o seguinte código.

```
private void TabsCadastro(int visualizar,int origem)
{
    TabSpec abaCLiente,abaEndereco,abaContrato;
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();


    abaCLiente = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
    abaCLiente.setContent(R.id.clientes);
    abaCLiente.setIndicator("Cliente");


    abaEndereco = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag2");
    abaEndereco.setContent(R.id.endereco);
    abaEndereco.setIndicator("Endereço");


    abaContrato = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag3");
    abaContrato.setContent(R.id.contrato);
    abaContrato.setIndicator("Contrato");
    tabHost.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);


    if(origem == 0)
    {
        tabHost.addTab(abaCLiente);
        tabHost.addTab(abaEndereco);
        tabHost.addTab(abaContrato);
    }
    tabHost.getTabWidget().setEnabled(false);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

}
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para alterar o  foco das abas? Gostaria de criar um botão para alterar o foco ao invés de clicar nas tabs para isso. Vou colocar um botão em cada aba para navegar entre elas já tentei usar

```
    setFocused(boolean),
    setFocusable(boolean),
```

mas não consegui mudar o foco.

Comment: Tens que fazer uso do [`setCurrentTab()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setCurrentTab%28int%29) para mudar de _tab_, algo tipo: `MainActivity.TabHost.setCurrentTab(1);`.

Comment: Acho que você não deveria usar mais TabHost, pois está muito ultrapassado. Usa ViewPager com essa biblioteca aqui:  https://github.com/bitjjj/PagerSlidingTitleIconTabStrip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu costumo fazer o seguinte:

```
private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
    tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();
    AddTab(this, this.tabHost, this.tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1")
            .setIndicator(addButton("Tab1")));
    AddTab(this, this.tabHost, this.tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2")
            .setIndicator(addButton("Tab2")));
    AddTab(this, this.tabHost, this.tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3")
            .setIndicator(addButton("Tab3")));
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}

public Button addButton(String texto) {
    Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsRelative = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            0, 0);
    button.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsRelative);
    button.setText(texto);
    return button;
}

private void intialiseViewPager() {
    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(new Fragment1());
    fragments.add(new Fragment2());
    fragments.add(new Fragment3());

    pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(),
            fragments);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}
```